# Send email from python webapp2 Google App Engine

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, webapp2

i am trying to send an email from my application. The code run successfully with out error. But it do not send the email. It show this message on Console.

```
You are not currently sending out real email. 
If you have sendmail installed you can use it by using the 
server with --enable_sendmail
```

The sample code provided by the google is:

```
message = mail.EmailMessage(
                    sender="shaizi9687@gmail.com",
                    subject="Your account has been approved")

message.to = "ABC <shahzebakram@hotmail.com>"
message.body = """Dear Albert:
Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
access new features.
Please let us know if you have any questions.
The example.com Team
"""
message.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the dev_appserver by default doesn't send out real mails.

Email sending **will work when you push to a live server**, for eg:

```
appcfg update /path/to/app/
```

But like the error message points out, you'll have to use the `--enable_sendmail` flag if you have sendmail installed on your system or use smtp flags, for eg:

```
dev_appserver /path/to/app/ --enable_sendmail=yes
```

or another eg using gmail as smtp provider

```
dev_appserver /path/to/app --smtp_host=smtp.gmail.com --smtp_port=465 \
--smtp_user=user@gmail.com --smtp_password=password
```

More explanation here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/

> **Mail and the development server**
>
> The development server can be configured to send email messages
>   directly from your computer when you test a feature of your app that
>   sends messages. You can configure the development server to use an
>   SMTP server of your choice. Alternatively, you can tell the
>   development server to use Sendmail, if Sendmail is installed on your
>   computer and set up for sending email.
>
> If you do not configure an SMTP server or enable Sendmail, when your
>   app calls the Mail service, the development server will log the
>   contents of the message. The message will not actually be sent.